# Cyclic values inside stress tensor in given configuration

Tags: classical-mechanics, computational-physics, stress-strain, software, solid-mechanics

i have majored in mechanical engineering and implemented a fully working FEM-Solver for structural mechanical problems for 2 and 3-dimensional problems. I have lately been working on bringing this to the web browser using web-assembly, opengl and a few other tools and it can be accessed via the following link:
[www.finneggers.de/fem](https://www.finneggers.de/fem/).

I have been playing around with my code while debugging some ui-buttons and randomly created the following model (squared solid, shape function is **second** order):

[image]

The gray arrows mean fixed supports at the given nodes. The green arrows are forces in the displayed direction (upwards here). When computing the results, I get reasonable results for basically any result type (displacement in x,y and total displacement). When looking at the stress-tensor I am seeing a surprising result for the stress-x entry of the stress tensor:

[image]

I have compared the results of my solver to Ansys in a few simplified test cases which makes me **assume that this result is in fact correct**. Now my question is: **Is there a qualitative explanation for why these 6-sided butterfly shapes occur around the spots of supports/loads?**

I am very happy if someone could quickly review this result and tell me what he/she thinks about the origin of the stress shape.

Comment: What do you mean by stress-$x$ entry?

Comment: well the stress tensor in this 2d case has 3 unique entries. on the main diagonal you have the stress-x and stress-y entries while on on S_12 = S_21 you have the shear stress.

Comment: so, it's a 2D case. Planar stress or strain simulation?

Comment: planar stress I guess

Comment: I have an answer in mind involving Green’s tensor for a lateral load on an infinite medium. Could you please upload the corresponding stress fields for the $y$ stress and the von Mises stress?

Comment: I closed the site so i quickly remodeled it. maybe the bc is off by a few nodes but results still the same.

x-stress: https://prnt.sc/qxyAGIGEMVX9
y-stress: https://prnt.sc/Bq8bBbBAXC8t
xy-stress: https://prnt.sc/8dbuEZfJ5
mises: https://prnt.sc/dgc_MFj0oRSL

I edited the color range a little bit so that mises is better to understand (because of singularities near the loading point)

Comment: Would [scicomp.se] be a better home for this question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Thanks for uploading the other plots! I was drawn to this question because I [worked on](http://john.maloney.org/Papers/Influence%20of%20finite%20thickness%20and%20stiffness.pdf) lateral loads on compliant layers in the context of cell mechanosensitivity.)

This problem has a strong resemblance to the so-called Boussinesq or Cerruti problem of elasticity, that is, the stress and displacement fields that arise from applying a point force on an infinite or semi-infinite medium.

At the surface around a tangential load, the x-oriented (horizontal in the image, right?) stress $\sigma_x$ is predicted to have the form

$$\sigma_x=-\frac{3P}{2\pi r^2}\cos\theta\sin^2\theta,$$

where $P$ is the load, $r$ is the distance from the point of load application, and $\theta$ is measured from vertical in the image (the y-axis). I simplified the result to assume a Poisson ratio of 1/2, as the more general solution is somewhat more intricate without altering the present conclusions. You'll note that this expression predicts the diagonal lobes of $\sigma_x$. We'd expect compression ahead of the load and tension behind it, but directly to the front and back of the load ($\sin\theta=0$) and to the sides ($\cos\theta=0$), there's no driving force to produce a nonzero x-direction normal stress $\sigma_x$.

What about the vertical lobes? I hypothesize that they arise from the left and right constraints, which introduce a bending mode characterized by tension (positive $\sigma_x$) in front of the load and compression (negative $\sigma_x$) behind it. I expect that they'd disappear if the edges were uniformly constrained, but that remains to be seen.

Comment: Yeah I thought about the last part too. The vertical lobes probably arise from the bending. I can run a secondary test when I am home. Thanks a lot for your insight! It’s interesting that there exists an analytical solution for a related Problem. Thanks a lot!